# Use Hurwitz theorem to show that the equation $cos(z)=\frac{i}{n} + exp(z/n)$ has a solution in $B(0,\delta)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\delta>0$. Use Hurwitz theorem to show that the equation $cos(z)=\frac{i}{n} + exp(z/n)$ has a solution in  $B(0,\delta)$ for $n$ large enough.

What I have tried: I have shown that $\frac{i}{n} + exp(z/n)$ converges to 1 uniformly. However, that doesn't help much because this is a constant function. I thought that maybe since $cos(0)=1$ and $cos(z)$ is analytic and would be close to $1$ in $B(0,\delta)$ for small $\delta$ it might be possible to show that $\frac{i}{n} + exp(z/n)$  converges locally uniformly to $cos(z)$. But this seems to be a stretch and I haven't been able to prove the latter formally. I am having trouble getting a useful estimation of $|\frac{i}{n} + exp(z/n)-cos(z)|$ for $n$ large enough.

I would prefer a hint rather than a full answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using wikipedia:
$f_{n}(z)=exp(z/n) - cos(z) + \frac {i} {n} $ is holomorphic for every $k \in \mathbb N$ (you can prove that) in sn open conected set, $B(0, \delta)$.
$f_{n}(z)=exp(z/n) - cos(z) + \frac {i} {n} $ converges to $f(z)=1 - cos(z)$ as n aproaches $\infty$. f is holomorfic too.
f(0)=0 of order 2 (you can proof that).
then $\exists \rho , k \in \mathbb N / f_{k}$ has 2 zeros (counting multiplicity) in $B(0, \rho) $ counting multiplicity.